# Is there any benefit to assigning a view to same name vs to a new name in python?

Tags: python, numpy, object, memory, pep8

Suppose I am creating a new view on a python object, which is the only view I need going forward. Is there any difference between assigning it to a new name vs overwriting the original name? If yes, which is preferable?

For example, suppose I have some numpy array `arr`, and only need some reshaped version of it going forward. Is it okay to reassign the new view to `arr`, or should I give it a new name?

Example for clarity:

```
import numpy as np

# some array
arr = np.zeros([100, 1])

# option 1
arr = arr.reshape(10, 10)

# option 2
arr_newview = arr.reshape(10, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both are same as there is no pre-declaration of variables in python. Python works completely different from other programming languages like C++ or java.
Python variable assigning work as pointers when we assign any variable its actually pointing towards that particular data.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty opinion based, but I disagree with the existing answer.

I like to retain old names and create new, long, descriptive names for each step of a transformation. It's sometimes helpful when debugging, and allows you to see intermediate steps of a transformation of data, which I like for my thought process. It also helps make the code more "self documenting".

The major downside to creating new names however is that that maintains a reference to the old data, which will prevent the garbage collector from freeing it. If you overwrite the `arr` reference with a new object, the old object that `arr` referenced previously can now be freed (assuming `arr` was the only reference to it). I wouldn't worry about that though unless you're dealing with huge data and find that that's an actual concern. Do what makes more sense to you unless you have reason to believe that it will become a problem.

---

In this particular example though, if `reshape` is returning essentially a reference to the same object that `arr` already held, there will be no functional difference. Do whichever makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Another disadvantage to your preferred method is the number of names you have to come up with.. I tend to reuse names unless I see a benefit in creating new names...

Comment: @Vinzent I see that as an advantage! Similar to how coming up with good function names helps you think about what the strict purpose of a function is, coming up with good variable names forces you to actually think about what the purpose of the line is, and as mentioned, makes the code self-documenting. I subscribe to the belief that if you can't come up with a good name, you likely either have an incomplete idea about what you're writing, or you're attempting to do too much at once. I regularly rename functions and variables until everything sits well with me.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but in the code I write (scientific computing/ lots of math using numpy) I very often end up with one-liners that I need to split into 5-10 lines and neither of the sub-lines make any sense at all on their own but only serve to not make the line 1000 chars long. In this situation it is not a valid argument that "if you can't come up with a good name, you likely either have an incomplete idea about what you're writing, or you're attempting to do too much at once" This is simply often not the case when f.ex. defining large coefficient matrices etc.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions assigning a `numpy` `view`.  So even with reassignment, the original data buffer remains.  The 'rest' of the original array might be freed, but that's a minor memory use.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah, I missed that when reading the docs of `reshape`. It seemed like it necessarily returned a new object, but I'm seeing that that's not actually the case. I'll update.

Comment: @Vinzent That makes sense. I don't do much in the way of math-heavy programming, so I don't have a lot of experience with what you're describing. There may be exceptions (and there may be fields that are exceptions), but with what I typically write, I've found it to be a good guide.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The reshape example in my OP might not have been the best one. I was after new view object, but I agree it's not fully clear whether reshape returns a view or a copy. The documentation is a bit mysterious about that: "This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a copy."

Answer (score 1):

This totally gives help in ease of access.
Likewise, you will have less problem debugging it.
Besides these two major benefits on a high scale programming, there is no other advantage of assigning a new view to the name